Next.js App with Amplify SSR: API Always Returning Same Data—Cache Issue?
I deployed a Next.js application using the App Router with SSR on AWS Amplify. The app displays photos retrieved from S3, and users can upload new photos via the page, which are then stored in S3. After uploading, the app should call the API to update the displayed photos in real-time.
However, the API consistently returns the same data, and the updates are not reflected. I’ve already checked potential caching issues but couldn’t find any solution.
Has anyone faced a similar issue, or do you have any insights on how to resolve this? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
This is api/list/route.tsx source code.
import { S3Client, ListObjectsV2Command } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const s3 = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_REGION!,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID!,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY!,
  },
});

export async function GET() {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store'); // キャッシュを無効化

  try {
    const command = new ListObjectsV2Command({
      Bucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_S3_BUCKET!,
    });

    const { Contents } = await s3.send(command);

    const files =
      Contents?.map((file) => ({
        key: file.Key!,
        lastModified: file.LastModified!,
        size: file.Size!,
        url: `https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_S3_BUCKET}.s3.${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${file.Key}`,
      })) || [];

    return NextResponse.json(files);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching S3 objects:', error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Failed to fetch S3 objects' }, { status: 500 });
  }
}


You have to disable caching where you are fetching your data
